# ASP.NET with Entity Framework doesn't write new entry into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, .net-4.8

I am a programming apprentice working at a small project, and I am trying to figure out why I cannot write a new dataset into my database with Entity Framework.

I have a web page that allows to the user to upload files that then get listed on that page with a repeater. The file gets saved to a folder within the project, and some data about the file should be written into the database (such as name, datetime, who uploaded it, and where it was uploaded to).

Here is the button that triggers the event:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" class="mb-3" />
```

And here is the click handler event:

```
protected void sBtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    if (fileUpload.HasFiles)
    {
        using (WS_TestEntities1 dbContext = new WS_TestEntities1())
        {
            if (dbContext != null)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in fileUpload.PostedFiles)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName;
                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                    fileUpload.Attributes.Clear();

                    Statuten newStatut = new Statuten
                    {
                        sName = "name",
                        sDatenpfad = "path",
                        sUploadDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        sUploadId = "Hans Maier"
                    };
                    dbContext.Statutens.Add(newStatut);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am passing some arbitrary values, to just prove that the thing works. I am getting an error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

`Statuten` just means `Documents` in this case (it's German).

The error gets triggered at the `SaveChanges` call, but problems arise before that in the `Add(newStatut)` function call. Both the `Buffer` and the `Cache` properties of the `Add(newStatut)` trigger a `System.Web.HttpException`, as do `Request`, `Response`, `IsValid`, `ContentType` etc. the id is for some reason a zero (0). Did I mess something up with EF? Or is it a more basic problem?

I have tried reloading the object from the db and some other basic things, as well as just changing a value at an index with

```
var statuten = dbContext.Statutens.ToList();
statuten[1].sName = "kaspar";
```

to see if I can even change a cell in the DB, but it didn't work.

Update 1:
I took DB-first approach since its just for testing. `public virtual DbSet<Statuten> Statutens { get; set; }` is the object within the Model.Context.cs, and the composition of it is as follows:

```
    public partial class Statuten
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string sName { get; set; }
        public string sDatenpfad { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> sUploadDateTime { get; set; }
        public string sUploadId { get; set; }
    }
```

The DB context itself looks like this

```
public partial class WS_TestEntities1 : DbContext
{
    public WS_TestEntities1()
        : base("name=WS_TestEntities1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<...> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<...> Apts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<...> Loans { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<...> Firms{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Statuten> Statutens { get; set; }
}
```

Update 2:
Error text and stack trace.

~Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.~

~Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.~

Source Error:

```
Line 93:                             
Line 94:                     }
Line 95:                     dbContext.SaveChanges();
Line 96:                 }
Line 97:             }
```

~Source File: C:\Users...\Statuten.aspx.cs    Line: 95~

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute.GetHashCode() +32
   System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj) +22
   System.Linq.Set`1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value) +74
   System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add) +40
   System.Linq.<ExceptIterator>d__73`1.MoveNext() +291
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +452
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +68
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +74
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildPropertyValidator(PropertyInfo clrProperty) +29
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildValidatorsForProperties(IEnumerable`1 clrProperties, IEnumerable`1 edmProperties, IEnumerable`1 navigationProperties) +1197
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildTypeValidator(Type clrType, IEnumerable`1 edmProperties, IEnumerable`1 navigationProperties, Func`3 validatorFactoryFunc) +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildEntityValidator(InternalEntityEntry entityEntry) +240
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationProvider.GetEntityValidator(InternalEntityEntry entityEntry) +95
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetValidationResult(IDictionary`2 items) +67
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors() +329
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +44
   WS_Test_Elemente.Statuten.sBtnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\kaspar.schultess\source\repos\WS_Test_Elemente\WS_Test_Elemente\Statuten.aspx.cs:95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +137
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +149
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5439
```

Comment: How did you define your WS_TestEntities1?

Comment: Are you able to show us code for the dbContext WS_TestEntities1? Another thing to try is to put dbContext.SaveChanges() outside of the foreach loop. What you're doing here with calling SaveChanges() on each iteration is not best practice.

Comment: Put `SaveChanges` out of the loop. This is a serious bug. `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes in a single database transaction. If you don't call it, all changes are discarded. Right now the code is broken and results in inconsistent data in case of error - never mind the delays caused by making 100 database calls instead of 1

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper have added an update to the post, I hope this is enough information, will provide more if needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have done this, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Alex I have made an update, tell me if you need more information

Comment: @Kaspar the NRE has nothing to do with EF. The way you use `SaveChanges` means you can't roll back changes made before the error though. The real problem is in the application code. At the very least specify which line throws. Debug your code to see which line fails and which of the variables used there is null. Post the actual *full* exception text, not just the message. That includes the line number where the error was thrown and a stack trace that shows which function threw and how execution got there

Comment: Don't call methods without understanding what they do either. Some of the code is meaningless, like `if (dbContext != null)` when you've just created the DbContext. The variable will never be empty. `fileUpload.Attributes.Clear();` on the other hand modifies the `FileUpload` control itself while you're iterating its contents.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Included in update 2

Comment: That means you didn't post the real code. The stack trace shows you tried to persist `System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute` to the database. What are the *real* entities and the types of their properties? Are any validations applied?